# Magic Square 3x3 c++

Tags: c++

our teacher told us to make a c++ program that generates a magic square 3x3 or higher and this is what i've gotten so far but its not working. 
help me please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
// A  B  C
// D  E  F
// G  H  I
int main()
{
srand(time(0));
int A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I;
do
{A=rand()%9+1;
B=rand()%9+1;
C=rand()%9+1;
D=rand()%9+1;
E=rand()%9+1;
F=rand()%9+1;
G=rand()%9+1;
H=rand()%9+1;
I=rand()%9+1;}
while ((A+B+C!=15) && (D+E+F!=15) && (G+H+I!=15) && (A+D+G!=15) && (B+E+H!=15) && (C+F+I!=15) &&
      (A+E+I!=15) && (C+E+G!=15) && (A!=B!=C!=D!=E!=F!=G!=H!=I));
      cout<<A<<" "<<B<<" "<<C<<endl;
      cout<<D<<" "<<E<<" "<<F<<endl;
      cout<<G<<" "<<H<<" "<<I<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: **What** is not working?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a clear problem statement.

Comment: `A!=B!=C!=D!=E!=F!=G!=H!=I` conditional statements don't chain like this. After the first comparison, every other comparison checks against `true` or `false`.

Comment: can you type it for me... sorry new here

Comment: please don't edit the quesion removing the part that was wrong.

Comment: @Mike The code is not working! :P

Comment: Nice algorithm, next let's implement a bogosort!

Comment: You need to be more specific. For example, does the code compile? Does it run? Are you getting any errors? What are the errors? What is the expected output and actual output?

Comment: @CompuChip that comment seems a little unkind, no? Maybe suggesting something effective instead of poking fun at the current approach would be more constructive.

Comment: @PunDefeated The C++ section of SO is a very unkind crypt.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `A!=B!=C!=D` you should likely write `A!=B && B!=C && C!=D`, or perhaps `!(A==B || B==C || C==D)`. The way you write it, the first comparison will result in an bool, which will then be compared to the next value.

Comment: Also he need to add A != C because if Values will be `A=1; B = 2; C=1` your expression will return `true` but result need to be `false` =) EDIT: Much beter

Comment: I dont get this can someone post it fully workig so i cant study it

Comment: From what I've seen, users here will be hesitant to fully solve your problem. We're more likely to point you in the correct direction and let you figure it out from there.